# How to add other language translation in magneto 2 programmatically

Tags: magento2

I have two languages with website one is English and second is danish.
When I add product programmatically into Magento 2. I am adding meta title

Example meta title :plakater på tilbud

By doing

```
$categoryTra->setMetaTitle($row["meta_title"]);
```

However its break with special character "**å**" ,

It only saves the title:plakater p in meta title and skips the words after special character "å tilbud"

Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: Have you tried htmlentities($str) function like $categoryTra->setMetaTitle(htmlentities($row["meta_title"]));

Comment: yes but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I was importing product names from a database and querying database ,return result was not coming in UTF-8 formate. I have added

mysqli_query($conn2,"SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($conn2,"SET SESSION collation_connection ='utf8_unicode_ci'");

Before the actual query

$resultQueryTbleProducts = mysqli_query($conn2, $queryTbleProducts);

than everything works fine. Hope this will help someone else in such a situation.